# Make a global minor mode buffer-local

Tags: emacs, buffer

Another Elisp package defines a minor mode as global. In other words, the package defines the minor mode with:

```
(define-minor-mode some-minor-mode
  ;; ... other stuff ...
  :global t)
```

I'd like to make it buffer-local so that when I activate it, it only applies to the buffer in which it is activated. How do I do this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew, I think that only applies to the [elisp] tag at S.E.?  Here at S.O., I believe it's valid to use it for "programming in elisp" questions.

Comment: @phils: I think it applies to SO as well. it should, at least (IMO). More specific programming-related tags should be used (and created if necessary).

Comment: It's not like adding a `java` or `python` tag. Most `emacs` questions involve use of elisp. Adding it everywhere in addition to `emacs` would be negative. Better to reserve it for questions *about the language itself*, not just some use of it. "How to do XYZ in Emacs?" will solicit answers that involve Elisp, and the question itself can make clear if it's only about how to do XYZ using Elisp.

Comment: Are any other programming language tags used that way at S.O.? AFAIK the tags for programming languages are widely used for tagging questions about programming *using* that language.  At E.S. the context is *already* Emacs and so "programming with elisp" will invariably be implicit, so the [elisp] definition is reasonable over there.  We might say that the inclusion of an [emacs] tag at S.O. provides the same context as E.S., but I nevertheless don't see why [elisp] would be used differently at S.O. to any other language tag.

Comment: At minimum, there's a large history of questions which are not tagged that way, so the consistency is not there.  I think this would need Meta discussion and general agreement.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Or at least, you can't in a generic way.

When a minor mode is defined as global, the logic of the mode will undoubtedly make that exact same assumption, and there's no generic change you could make which would cause *any arbitrary global minor mode* to have only buffer-local effects.

Furthermore, for some global modes a buffer-local variant wouldn't even *make sense*, such as modes which affect window configurations or frame parameters.

Global modes have to be treated on a case-by-case basis, looking at their specific implementation details.  Depending on the code in question, you *might* be able to achieve your goal for some particular mode; but that same approach would not be guaranteed to work for all global modes.

It's worth mentioning that there are "globalized" minor modes which blend the other two concepts, by taking an existing buffer-local minor mode, and then defining a global mode which enables or disables the buffer-local mode en masse in all of the applicable buffers.  You can't go in the other direction, though -- if you don't *already* have a buffer-local mode, then you would have to write that first.